# How to overwrite/replace specific rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, overwrite

I have a dataset containing some data obtained after a correction that should be merged with the primary dataset. I need a way to overwrite the old values with the new ones, but I don't know how.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
Data <- data.frame(ID = c("Gfa","Gfa","Gfa","Pka","Pka","Pka"),
                Treatment = c("Control","T1","T2","Control","T1","T2"),
                Value = c(3,4,6,2,9,7))
                         
Data_new <- data.frame(ID = c("Gfa","Pka","Pka"),
                Treatment = c("Control","Control","T2"),
                Value = c(5,2,8))
```

How can I merge the `Data_new` to the `Data`, overwriting only the new values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  rows_update(Data_new, by = c("ID", "Treatment"))


Result

   ID Treatment Value
1 Gfa   Control     5
2 Gfa        T1     4
3 Gfa        T2     6
4 Pka   Control     2
5 Pka        T1     9
6 Pka        T2     8
```